# Which algorithm should I use for this use cases?

Tags: supervised-learning

I got data like:

1. Student age
2. Student study subject
3. Student gender
4. Student academic result
5. Student joined actives

and I got the student graduation income.

So, I would like to train a model, so that I can guest a student with some background and find back his / her projected income. If I would like to use machine learning to deal with this case, any ideas on how to implement? Please advise.

Comment: Look up Regression in your textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Features: *age*, *gender* and *academic result*: take as numeric values

*study subject* : encode the subjects *like 0 for maths, 1 for physics etc..*

for *joined actives* encode and use features like number of activities plus other columns as **highly important** activities having values encoded as 0 and 1.

Example:
``` age, gender, academic result, study subject, total_actives, debate, music``
24,  0,    , 90,            , 3            , 4            ,      1,     0 ```

Train your `XGBoost` regressor using the above features and voila!